# Android: height of LinearLayout didn't fill parent of ListView item

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, fill-parent

I have a ListView, the item is a RelativeLayout, at left is text, and the right side is ImageView in a LinearLayout. 
I expect the height of the LinearLayout**(white background)** to be fillParent but it didn't.
The effect is :
[image]
Anyone can help on this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_list_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_list_item_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_list_item_more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_list_item_delete_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_list_item_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_list_item_check_margin_lr"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_list_item_check_margin_lr"
            android:contentDescription="@string/none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ctx_del1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The main.xml is as below which contains the ListView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/adview_ayout">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- content end -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout_pb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_pb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Add `layout_alignParentTop` and `layout_alignParentBottom` attributes to the `LinearLayout`, and set them both to `true`.

Comment: please show your layout containing the listview

Comment: What LinearLayout? What do you really want?

Comment: make height fill_parent  if you want to show one item in on screen

Comment: added the main.xml and also specified the white background part should be fill the row height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is something that the parent `RelativeLayout` can't handle by itself - it creates kind of a vicious circle - parent defers the height to the child (`wrap_content` on the `RelativeLayout`) and the child defers the height to the parent (`match_parent` on main_list_item_delete_layout).
What you can do is to anchor the top of the main_list_item_delete_layout to the parent and its bottom to another view that is guaranteed to be the bottom (the `LinearLayout` on the left, containing the three text views):

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/left_layout" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_list_item_delete_layout"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/main_list_item_delete_layout"
        ...
     >
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_list_item_delete_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/left_layout"
        ...>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PS: in your example, in case the text on the left `LinearLayout` is too long, it will overflow and overlap the delete layout - hence the addition of the anchor I added to the left layout.
PS2: I know this solution is very customized to your layout. If you are set on using the `RelativeLayout` as a parent, you might want to try the new `ConstraintLayout`.